# cant update another user details while logged in

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm working on nodejs loopback application. I've a user logged in already and and an operation requires this user to find a `userById` and update a field.

```
     $scope.user = User.findById({
          id: sender.id
      });

  $scope.user.supplierId = currUserId;

  $scope.user.$save();
```

But its not working as required.

and I get following error:

```
PUT http://localhost:5000/api/users 401 (Unauthorized)
GET http://localhost:5000/api/AuthProviders/count 401 (Unauthorized)
401 while on router on login path
POST http://localhost:5000/api/users/login?include=user 400 (Bad Request)
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: are you using angularjs or angular sdk which they provide?

Comment: you can't use Models to access rest endpoints with regular angularjs code. however, you can access them using angular http. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For findById operation:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/User/' + sender.id + '?access_token=h9vpJ94zqN199ENWx'
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(error) {
    throw error;
});
```

Otherwise you can use [Angular SDK](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK) which makes it much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Vishal for extending your help. There was a flaw in modeling , now thats corrected and all is working fine.